# Custom component and router.php with category/speciality

Tags: php, joomla

I'm using Joomla 3.9
I've developed a custom component.
In my component I've this router code working.
This code works for :

1. Form searchs

/myform/first_speciality_alias

/myform/second_speciality_alias

2. List view

/myform/first_speciality_alias

/myform/second_speciality_alias

3. Details view

/myform/first_speciality_alias/third_reference

/myform/second_speciality_alias/fourth_reference

4. Access from direct URL

What is this router code doing ?
He synchronizes one of my form field with the URL.

The problem is, I also need speciality menu items.
But as soon as I create a speciality menu item ;

1. case 1 does :
   /myform/first_speciality_alias/first_speciality_alias
2. As soon as I click first_speciality_alias which exists in a menu, URLS becomes
   /myform/first_speciality_alias/first_speciality_alias
   /myform/first_speciality_alias/second_speciality_alias <= when I click second_speciality_alias in the form
3. Details view doesnt work, it shows list view.
4. Access from direct URL seems to work 1/2 time.

## mycomponent/router.php

```php
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
class MyComponentRouter extends JComponentRouterView
{   
    public function build(&$query)
    {
        $segments = array();
        if (isset($query['idspeciality']))
        {
            $db = JFactory::getDbo();
            $qry = $db->getQuery(true);
            $qry->select('alias');
            $qry->from('speciality');
            $qry->where('id = ' . $db->quote($query['idspeciality']));
            $db->setQuery($qry);
            $alias = $db->loadResult();
            $segments[] = $alias;
            unset($query['idspeciality']);
        }
        if (isset($query['reference']))
        {
            $segments[] = $query['reference'];
            unset($query['reference']);
        }
        unset($query['view']);
        return $segments;
    }
  
    public function parse(&$segments)
    {
        $vars = array();
    
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $qry = $db->getQuery(true);
        $qry->select('id');
        $qry->from('speciality');
        $qry->where('alias = ' . $db->quote($segments[0]));
        $db->setQuery($qry);
        $id = $db->loadResult();
    
        if(!empty($id))
        {
            $vars['idspeciality'] = $id;
            $vars['view'] = 'mylistview';
        }
        if(!empty($segments[1]))
        {
            $vars['reference'] = $segments[1];
            $vars['view'] = 'mydetailsview';
        }

        return $vars;
    }
}
```

## mycomponent/views/mylistview/tmpl/view.html.php

```php
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
class MyComponentViewMyComponent extends JViewLegacy {
    function display($tpl = null) {
        
        ...
        
        $speciality_from_url = JRequest::getVar('idspeciality');
        # If POST speciality sent I rewrite to the correct URL
        if(isset($_POST['secteur'])){
            $session->set('idspeciality', $_POST['secteur']);
            $url = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=mylistview'.'&idspeciality=' . $session->get('idspeciality'), false);
            $app->redirect($url);
            return false;
        }
        elseif($speciality_from_url != $session->get('idspeciality')){
            $session->set('idspeciality', $speciality_from_url);
            $url = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=mylistview'.'&idspeciality=' . $session->get('idspeciality'), false);
            $app->redirect($url);
            return false;
        }
        
        ...
        
    }
}
```

## mycomponent/views/mylistview/tmpl/default.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metadata>
    <layout title="List view">
        <message>List view.</message>
    </layout>
            <fields
            name="request"
                        addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_mycomponent/models/fields"
            >
        <fieldset name="request">
            <field
                    name="idspeciality"
                    type="customtype"
                    label="Speciality"
                    description="Sort list view"
                    >
                <option value="">Pick one</option>
            </field>
        </fieldset>
    </fields>

</metadata>
```

Comment: Please make a custom flag to request that this Joomla question to [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.